# Using 'didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock' with Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a custom `UITableView` that takes care of animations for rearranging cells and works perfectly with standard test array which doesn't use core data.

When trying with an application that uses core data with two entities 'Folder' and 'Item' with a `To Many` relationships I receive an error.

> [(Item)] does not have a member called exchangeObjectAtIndex

for;

```
tableView.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock = {(fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

let delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context: NSManagedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext!

self.itemsArray.exchangeObjectAtIndex(toIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: fromIndexPath.row)

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) { abort() }

}
```

This is because:

> The NSSet, NSMutableSet, and NSCountedSet classes declare the
>   programmatic interface to an unordered collection of objects.

So I tried converting the NSSet to an NSMutableArray to manage the objects order.

```
func itemsMutableArray() -> NSMutableArray {
    return NSMutableArray(array: (item.allObjects as! [Item]).sorted{ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending } )
}
```

But then I get the following error in my tableview; this was because the mutable array is an `AnyObject` so swift doesn't believe it has a title property.

> cell.textLabel?.text = folderMutableArray[indexPath.row].title

So then I go back to where I started. I am just trying to create a simple list and rearrange the order of objects.

Here is my `Folder` Class:

```
class Folder: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var item: NSSet

/// Method 1 - Converting to a NSMutableArray

// func itemsMutableArray() -> NSMutableArray {
//    return NSMutableArray(array: (item.allObjects as! [Item]).sorted{ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending } )
// }


// Method 2 - creating an array of type Item
func itemArray() -> [Item] {
    let sortByDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "Date", ascending: true)
    return item.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortByDate]) as! [Item]
}
}
```

Productivity apps do this all the time so I know it's possible but unsure how, Does anyone know where I am going wrong or have any ideas or suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy to achieve. You need to add a property called `index` to your `Item`. Set it to an integer type and whenever you add a new `Item` set this value to the index under which you want an item to appear. This property should be added both in Core Data Model and in your Item's class as `NSManaged` property.

Next you need to add a transient property to your `Folder` class called `arrayOfItems` (you can rename this of course to whatever you want). In Core Data Model set it to Transient and Transformable.

In your `Folder` class do the following:

```
class Folder: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged var title: String
    @NSManaged var item: NSSet
    @NSManaged var arrayOfItems: [Items]

    override func awakeFromFetch() {
        super.awakeFromFetch()
        self.regenerateItems()
    }

    func regenerateItems() {
        let desc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: true)
        if let array = item.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([desc]) as? [Item] {
            self.arrayOfItems = array
        }
    }

}
```

Now whenever you fetch any instance of `Folder` you will get a correct sorted and mutable array of `Item`s. There are only two other cases you need to consider.

And they result from the fact that `awakeFromFetch` is only getting called when you fetch your data from Core Data. So, you have to consider other scenarios.

## Adding new `Item`

When you add new `Item` you need to either manually append the new `Item` to `arrayOfItems` or you need to call `regenerateItems()` once you are finished adding the new `Item`. For example, lets assume that somewhere in your code you create your initial data:

```
var folder = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Folder", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Folder
var firstItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Item
// assuming that you have an inverse relationship from Item to Folder
// line below will assign it and will add your firstItem to Folder's
// NSSet of items
firstItem.folder = folder

// at this point your firstItem is added to your Folder but
// arrayOfItems is empty. So, you should call
folder.arrayOfItems = [firstItem]
// or you can call folder.regenerateItems()
```

Code above refers to the situation when you create your **initial** data. If somewhere in your code you add a new `Item` to the folder which already has some `Items` you have the following:

```
var newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Item
// assuming that you have an inverse relationship from Item to Folder
// line below will assign it and will add your newItem to Folder's
// NSSet of items
newItem.folder = someExistingFolder

// at this point your newItem is added to your Folder but
// arrayOfItems is not yep updated and does not include newItem
// so you should either call
folder.arrayOfItems.append(newItem)
// or you can call folder.regenerateItems()
```

## Rearranging `Items`

Also, when you move `Item`s in your table view you will need to change their index and order in the `arrayOfItems`. The easiest way to achieve this would probably be to change the order of items in the `arrayOfItems` and then to iterate through this array assigning correct new indexes to all items within it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let itemThatMoved = currentFolder.arrayOfItems[sourceIndexPath.row]
    currentFolder.arrayOfItems.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
    currentFolder.arrayOfItems.insert(itemThatMoved, atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row )
    var currentIndex = 0
    for item in currentFolder.arrayOfItems {
        item.index=currentIndex
        currentIndex++
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions.

P.S. I strongly encourage you to change the name of your relationship from `item` to `items`. Plural name `items` is much more logical for `NSSet`.

Comment: Thank you so much for that reply, really informative. Did some code refactoring and updated the Core Data model and the Classes as you suggested. 

I understand the updates so far but unsure what you mean about when adding an Item to a Folder. Why do I need to append to arrayOfItems when that creates an array of the Items anyway ? or why do I need to call `regenerateItems()` after ? The reason I ask is to completely understand the code rather than blindly updating the code hoping for results. I updated my question with the code to add an item

Comment: Give me couple of minutes I will expand on this in my answer

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, thank you so much for your help I really do appreciate it ! Very informative. Still working on a bug which when I move a cell the other cells change their names to the cell they are replacing. E.g. if their are 5 cells - 1,2,3,4,5 and I place 3 at the end where 5 should be instead of 1,2,4,5,3 the other cells update their text to the replacing cell e.g. 1,2,3(4),4(5),3(moved cell)

Comment: @JKSDEV are you populating your cells from the currentFolder.arrayOfItems array or are you using some other array? I am using identical code to the one I posted and it works fine when cells are rearranged, so it is very strange that it doesn't work for you :(

Comment: I am directly using the `selectedFolder.arrayOfItems`  when populating the cells e.g.  `cell.textLabel?.text = selectedFolder.arrayOfItems[indexPath.row].item`   &      `returnCount = selectedFolder.arrayOfItems`

Comment: 'cell.textLabel?.text = selectedFolder.arrayofItems[indexPath.row].item' - what does .item property store?

Comment: sorry it's actually .title which is of type string, the name of the item for the cell label text.

Comment: Can you print to the console selectedFolder.arrayOfItems after we rearrange it in the moveRowAtIndexPath to check that items are correctly rearranged within that array?

Comment: Check my question for the code, the console prints "end of didmovecell function" the number of times a cell has updated its position. So if I move 1 in 1,2,3,4,5, to where five is the console prints 4 times for 2,3,4,5

Comment: @JKSDEV hey, I can't see the new code with the console output. Are you sure that you have updated the question? Or did you create a new question? Can you then post the link to it?

Comment: Sorry and removed the code and created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387431/rearranging-cells-in-uitableview-bug-saving-changes - It seems my idea of saving wasn't working and the bug persists.