# Rearranging Cells in UITableView Bug & Saving Changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

When rearranging cells in my **custom** `UITableView` I am encountering a bug where for e.g.

If I am rearranging 1,2,3,4,5 and I move cell 1 to the end where cell 5 is then what happens is all the cells rename themselves to whichever cell they are replacing. So instead of the new order being 2,3,4,5,1 it becomes 1(2),2(3),3(4),4(5),1(moved cell).

In my core data model I have two entities one for **Folder** and another for **Items**. It is a to many relationship of type `NSSet` so Folder can have many Items. Items have a property called `index` of type `Int` and **represents the items order in the array** & the Folder has transient property called `arrayOfItems` which of type transformable. This returns an array of the Items ordered by their index value.

The console prints out `end of didmovecell function` **but not** `Moved cell`.

```
table.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock = {(fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let itemThatMoved = self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems[sourceIndexPath.row]
   self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
   self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems.insert(itemThatMoved, atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row )

    var currentIndex = 0
    for item in self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems {
     item.index=currentIndex
     currentIndex++

     println("Moved cell")
    }
   }
 println("end of didmovecell function")
}
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and how I can save the changes to my core data model e.g. updating the item Index value.

PS: I have tested `didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock` for my custom UITableView **without using core data** with a basic array called Objects. It worked fine with something like this;

```
 table.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock = {(fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in
    self.objects.exchangeObjectAtIndex(toIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: fromIndexPath.row)
  }
```

Comment: Can you please illustrate how you are using this code? I don't quite understand why you are wrapping the moveRowAtIndexPath function into the block. Also, can you let me know if "Moved cell" is ever printed

Comment: I have a custom UITableView with animations that take care of actions so `table.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock` is the custom table and it's method for handling the animations. As I mentioned in the question "Moved Cell" doesn't actually get printed but the cells do change position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you need to keep the blocks then change your code to:

```
table.didMoveCellFromIndexPathToIndexPathBlock = {(fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Void in

   let itemThatMoved = self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems[fromIndexPath.row]
   self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
   self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems.insert(itemThatMoved, atIndex:toIndexPath.row )

   var currentIndex = 0
   for item in self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems {
      item.index=currentIndex
      currentIndex++
   }

   // at this point call saveContext() to ensure that rearrangement is saved in Core Data
}
```

Previously you had a function wrapped in your block. You were calling the block but the function within it was never called :)

Comment: Great !! School boy error :/ Should of know better. And because I am directly working with the data no need to call an extra save.

Comment: You don't need to call an extra save only if you are sure that your data will be saved at some point later on. However, if you are not sure you should absolutely save your context after making changes to it :)